# Could the green numbers be clearer again?

Tags: discussion, design

The accepted answers with solid green backed looked better to me.

I guess I am finding that

[image]

is starting to become harder to read than

[image]

Comment: I like how the new graphics make it feel more like dry erase marker on a whiteboard (very apropos given the site's purpose), but they are a little light in places.